# all containers remove themselves instead of one at a time

Tags: javascript, html, css

Sorry, I repost the problem:

I want to remove a single container when their border right x become inferior to the border left x of their parent. It work fine with visibility hidden, but not with remove() as it remove all the containers.

Here the complete code of the problem...

Here is the JavaScript, for what the result is unexpected

```js
let isPassed = setInterval(function() {
  let containers = document.querySelectorAll(".container");
  let division = document.querySelector(".division")
  containers.forEach((container) => {
    let containerRight = parseInt(container.getBoundingClientRect().right);
    let zoneLeft = parseInt(division.getBoundingClientRect().left);
    if (containerRight <= zoneLeft) {
      //container.style.visibility = "hidden"; // work fine
      //container.style.display = "none";  // hide all the container
      container.remove() // remove all the container
    }
  })
}, 100);
```

```css
body,
html {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.division {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 320px;
  height: 128px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 128px;
  width: 64px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  visibility: visible;
  animation: translation 5s linear;
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.container>div {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

@keyframes translation {
  0% {
    right: 64px;
  }
  100% {
    right: 896px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="division">
  <div class="container A">
    <div class="box1"></div>
    <div class="box2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container A">
    <div class="box1"></div>
    <div class="box2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container A">
    <div class="box1"></div>
    <div class="box2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container A">
    <div class="box1"></div>
    <div class="box2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container A">
    <div class="box1"></div>
    <div class="box2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `remove()` the most left `container`, the other contains will move over to fill the gap that is there by `removing` the previous containers.

When they move, they instantly match your `if`, and therefore they are removed them self.

---

#### Fix 1

Use `justify-content: flex-end;` on the `.division` so that the containers are aligned from the end of the box, so it won't overlap if you remove any of them. This way `remove()` will work as expected

###### ```js
let isPassed = setInterval(function() {
  let containers = document.querySelectorAll(".container");
  let division = document.querySelector(".division")
  containers.forEach((container) => {
    let containerRight = parseInt(container.getBoundingClientRect().right);
    let zoneLeft = parseInt(division.getBoundingClientRect().left);
    if (containerRight <= zoneLeft) {
        container.remove();
    }
  })
}, 100);
```

```css
body,
html {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.division {
justify-content: flex-end;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 320px;
  height: 128px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 128px;
  width: 64px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  visibility: visible;
  animation: translation 5s linear;
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.container>div {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

@keyframes translation {
  0% {
    right: 64px;
  }
  100% {
    right: 896px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="division">
  
  <div class="container A">
    <div class="box1"></div>
    <div class="box2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container A">
    <div class="box1"></div>
    <div class="box2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container A">
    <div class="box1"></div>
    <div class="box2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container A">
    <div class="box1"></div>
    <div class="box2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

#### Fix 2

Using `style.visibility = "hidden"` is your best option, if you don't want to change the HTML/CSS to prevent the moving of the containers when you `remove()` one.

###### ```js
let isPassed = setInterval(function() {
  let containers = document.querySelectorAll(".container");
  let division = document.querySelector(".division")
  containers.forEach((container) => {
    let containerRight = parseInt(container.getBoundingClientRect().right);
    let zoneLeft = parseInt(division.getBoundingClientRect().left);
    if (containerRight <= zoneLeft) {
        container.style.visibility = "hidden"; // work fine
    }
  })
}, 100);
```

```css
body,
html {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.division {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 320px;
  height: 128px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 128px;
  width: 64px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  visibility: visible;
  animation: translation 5s linear;
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.container>div {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

@keyframes translation {
  0% {
    right: 64px;
  }
  100% {
    right: 896px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="division">
  <div class="container A">
    <div class="box1"></div>
    <div class="box2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container A">
    <div class="box1"></div>
    <div class="box2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container A">
    <div class="box1"></div>
    <div class="box2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container A">
    <div class="box1"></div>
    <div class="box2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container A">
    <div class="box1"></div>
    <div class="box2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```